# Socket.io initialization resulting in a 404 network error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am using nodejs and express to create a basic chat app and I'm getting a network 404 error message when trying to initialize the socket.io object.

```
<script src="/javascripts/socket.io/socket.io.js-client"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io.connect();
</script>
```

Tha above code results in a 404 error for some polling call

```
"NetworkError" 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1432851505880-89
```

I need the polling to run using the following url instead: `http://localhost:3000/javascripts/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1432851505880-89`

because I am using express, but not sure how to accomplish this.

Server Side Code:

```
var app = express();

var server = require( "http" ).createServer( app );
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

server.listen(8888);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('send message', function(data){
    io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I have been trying to troubleshoot this one for quite a while now with no success. I appreciate any advice. Commenting out the var `socket = io.connect()` resolves the error. Appreciate any advice.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your server-side socket.io code.  The URL that the client is using to connect the webSocket is the default URL for a socket.io connection so that looks correct unless you've done something custom on the server.  If you have done something custom on the server, then we need to see what that is.

Answer (score 2):

Your web page is apparently running on port 3000, but your socket.io server is listening on port 8888.  The two must be the same port so it is no surprise that there is no response for a socket.io request on port 3000 (since your socket.io server is listening on port 8888).

Because the default URL it is trying is port 3000, then that must be the port that your web page is one and it must be served by a different web server.  If that is the case, then you will need to do one of two things:

1. Combine the web server that serves your web pages with the socket.io server so the same server is taking care of both.
2. Specify the port in the client request and enable your socket.io server for cross-origin requests.

To specify the port in the client request, you can do this:

```
<script src="http://myserver.com:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io("http://yourserver.com:8888");
</script>
```

Note, that this is requesting the client socket.io library from the express server where your socket.io server is (so it's using the same port that your socket.io server is running on).

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML where socket.io client javascript is being served is *not* also being served by express at port `8888` (it looks like the html is coming from port `3000`), you may just need to configure the socket.io client to point at the port where the server-side socket.io has been setup to listen (`8888`):

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost:8888');
```